# How do you attach a debugger to a Web service?

Tags: web-services, debugging

I am using a Web service. Can anybody tell me how to debug through it?

Answer (score 2):

Attach to the instance of w3wp.exe in which your application pool is executing.

Answer (score 1):

this solution is for debugging asmx or wcf-webservices:
attach to the process of the service (w3wp), not the client!

Answer (score 1):

That all depends, do you have the webservice, or are you trying to debug the webservice through an application that connects to the webservice?

Answer (score 1):

If you have control over the webservice, it's as simple as adding it to your solution,  running it from localhost (or a server you have the proper credentials for) and then stepping into it through the IDE.

If you don't have control over it, you're out of luck and at the mercy of whomever is providing it.

Answer (score 0):

Debugger.Launch();

when you add this to your code(which is back of your server) you can debug