# How to debug through web service

Tags: c#, web-services

Using VS 2005 SP1
 I have a solution which contains an windows project and a web service project. The windows
application calls the web service. I have a breakpoint in the first line in the web service method. When I run the windows app in debug mode, the call to the web service gets executed and returns but the breakpoint in the web service doesn't get triggered.

Is there a special set up to get the debugger to single into the web service?

Comment: Dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/666226/how-do-you-attach-a-debugger-to-a-web-service

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to tell visual studio to start both projects when you're debugging.  Try right-clicking on the solution in Solution Explorer, then select 'Multiple Startup Projects'.  Change the action of each project you want to debug to 'Start'.

Comment: first you gotta change the url from your iis-url to the new port url from vs ... then it works ... otherwise, simply attach to another process!

Comment: True.  I wasn't thinking about IIS...I'm too used to debugging with cassini now :).